# How do I wait to run the next npm command after the current command is complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I know, it sounds simple. But read on to see the challenge I'm facing.

I am trying to create an 'init' command, to assist in setting up a cloned repo for development. We utilize a remote package manager, requiring the developer to have an `.npmrc` file in the repository when working on a package (We don't want to restrict the user by using a global `.npmrc` file). The process should work like this:

- prompt user for their username in the terminal
- write the `.npmrc` file to their system
- run `npm i`
- run `npm run build`

I created a new `script` in my `package.json`:

```
"init": "node ./scripts/writeNpmRc.js && npm i && npm run build && node ./scripts/init.js"
```

My `writeNpmRc.js` file uses `readline` to get the user input, then writes the file (remember, at this point we have not yet run `npm i`, so we're working with what's installed by node).

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const writeFile = function(dest, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(dest, data, 'utf-8', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

const getUsername = () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      rl.question(
        'What is your username (typically firstname.lastname)? ',
        result => {
          if (!result) {
            console.error('You must provide your username.');
            return getUsername();
          }
          resolve(result);
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
  return promise
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('[getUsername] ', err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      rl.close();
    });
};

(async () => {
  const userName = await getUsername();

  const fileData = `registry=http://my.remote.repo/url/
email=${userName}@email.com`;

  await writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../.npmrc'), fileData).catch(err => {
    console.err('[writeFile Error]', err);
  });

  console.log('[END writeNpmRcFile]');
  process.exit(0);
})();
```

This part appears to run fine, except that followup command (`npm i`) doesn't utilize the new `.npmrc` file and the install bombs. I can (after the failure) run `npm i` just fine, so the file content itself appears to be right. In fact, if I manually place a `.npmrc` file and run everything, *except* the `writeNpmRcFile.js`, it runs just fine. It's only when I chain this command that they fail.

I know I'm missing something, I just don't know what? I waited for the `fs.writeFile` to complete successfully (probably could've just use `writeFileSync`...). It's like the file system hasn't let go of the `.npmrc` file in time for the next command. I even setup a custom async `wait()` method, at one point, that held off for a second prior to exiting the process, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, (after briefly looking skimming over the [source code](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/b829d62c98506325d2afb2d85d191a8ff1c49157/lib/install.js)) npm has already determined what the config should be/is prior to the command(s) defined in your npm script(s) are evaluated and executed. In essence the `.npmrc` file that is generated via a npm script simply does not exist as as far a npm is concerned - it's already inferred the config settings prior to running your script command(s).

Comment: Now that makes sense. I wonder if (rather than chaining my commands in the script line) I could use `child_process` to run each additional command? Or, at minimum, the `npm i`, as that's the only one that relies on the `.npmrc`. As a child process, wouldn't it be a separate instance? (Think I just need to test this...)

Answer (score 0):

So, @RobC made a ton of sense in his comment, and I tested out my follow-on theory about using `child_process` to run the `npm i` step, after writing the `.npmrc` file. Testing showed that I thought right, it ran the command in a separate context, and that context would use the new file. For those that are curious, here is my updated `writeNpmRcFile.js` that includes the install.

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

let rl;
let spinnerInterval;

const getInterface = () =>
  readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

const writeFile = function(dest, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(dest, data, 'utf-8', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

const runInstall = () => {
  console.log('Running npm install (This may take a few, so be patient)');
  spinnerInterval = twirlTimer();
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(
      'npm i',
      { cwd: path.resolve(__dirname, '../') },
      (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        clearInterval(spinnerInterval);
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        resolve();
      }
    );
  });
  return promise.catch(err => {
    clearInterval(spinnerInterval));
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};

const twirlTimer = function() {
  var P = ['\\', '|', '/', '-'];
  var x = 0;
  return setInterval(function() {
    process.stdout.write('\r' + P[x++]);
    x &= 3;
  }, 250);
};

const getUsername = () => {
  if (!rl) rl = getInterface();
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      rl.question(
        'What is your username (typically firstname.lastname)? ',
        result => {
          if (!result) {
            console.error('You must provide your username.');
            return getUsername();
          }
          resolve(result);
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
  return promise
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('[getUsername] ', err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      rl.close();
    });
};

(async () => {
  const userName = await getUsername();

  // prettier-ignore
  const fileData = `registry=http://my.remote.repo/url/
email=${userName}@email.com`;

  console.log(`Writing your '.npmrc' file to the directory`);
  await writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../.npmrc'), fileData).catch(err => {
    console.error('[writeFile Error] ', err);
  });

  await runInstall().catch(err => {
    console.log('[runInstall Error] ', err);
  });

  console.log('[END writeNpmRcFile]');
  process.exit(0);
})();
```

Having made this change my `package.json` `scripts` changes to this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./scripts",
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "release": "standard-version",
    "write-npmrc": "node ./scripts/writeNpmRcFile.js",
    "init": "npm run write-npmrc && npm run build && node ./scripts/init.js",
    "build": "node ./scripts/build.js"
  }
```